# Integrating $\partial_{t}{x}= a e^{-b t} -b x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can below integral be solved analytically? Could any clever guy help?

$\partial_{t}{x}= a e^{-b t} -b x$

Comment: $$\partial_{t}(e^{bt}x)=e^{bt}(\partial_tx+bx)= a\implies\ldots$$

Comment: Could you please write it completely. There is nothing to do after ... @Did

Comment: Do you mean you cannot complete this hint?

Comment: No, I mean you could post the answer and get score @Did

Comment: If you can complete this into a full prof, I suggest that you post the result as an answer.

Comment: Ok, and you get me the score please:)) @Did

Comment: I'm not sure I'm right or not

Comment: @Did could you complete it?

Comment: Yes I could (obviously) and I will not because if you cannot do it yourself, there is a real problem with you asking this...

Comment: Is it possible to find the answer even when x=x(t,k) and b=b(k) and a= a(k)? @Did